# Mongo bash script to create Db and collections

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell, ubuntu, vagrant

I'm using vagrant and trying to create some bash sentences to initialize my vagrant local machine like the server configuration:

I'm installing Mongo and everything was ok untill i need to create the database and some collections: I would like to do that:

```
mongo 
use redirect
db.createCollection("first")
db.createCollection("second")
db.createCollection("third")
exit
```

From my terminal and conecting to the machine with ssh is working, but i would like to make this process automatic, i have try to run the code exactly like above and is not working. Or something like:

```
mongo --shell use redirect
mongo --shell db.createCollection("first")
```

If somebody knows how to do this i will appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know that is non required to create the collections, when you start to use it Mongo will create it. On the other hand if you want to create some fixtures into the database assume the collection are already there.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the database you want to use as an argument to the mongo command. If it does not yet exist, it will be created for you. That probably solves your problem. See the  option in the manpage.

You can further specify a java expression for mongo to evaluate, using the --eval option. So the following will execute your code in, for example, bash:

```
$ mongo redirect --eval 'db.createCollection("first"); db.createCollection("second"); db.createCollection("third")'
MongoDB shell version v3.4.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/redirect
MongoDB server version: 3.4.9
{ "ok" : 1 }
$
```

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 possibilities for you to do that :

1. replace `--shell` with `--eval` (see http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#eval-option)

   ```
   mongo --shell db.createCollection("first")
   ```
2. put your sequence of step in a js file and run  (see http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#execute-a-javascript-file)

   ```
   mongo localhost:27017/test myjsfile.js
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'db.createCollection("first")' | mongo redirect
```

Comment: can you provide an explanation to backup your code?